# Deserialize JSON Object Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring, solr, jackson, spring-data, solrj

I have a solr backend configured as a Spring Data Repository.

```
package repository

import domain.Product
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository

interface ProductCatalogRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, String> {}
```

The product domain object is defined as

```
package domain
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.beans.Field
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.solr.core.mapping.SolrDocument

@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "myCore")
class Product {
    @Id
    val id: String? = null
    @Field("sku_product_mapping")
    val skuProductMapping: String? = null;
```

The solr document returned is

```
{
   "id": "FOO_166112",
   "sku_product_mapping": "{\"166112\": {\"size\": \"1.00\"}}"
}
```

I would like to change the `skuProductMapping` field to be a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` or something better. But I am unsure how to have Jackson parse the embedded JSON string in the Solr Document.

Answer (score 0):

JSON parsing with Jackson is the same, regardless if your `skuProductMapping` is a `String` or `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` or stronger typed `Map<Integer, Map<String, Double>>` or even stronger `SkuProductMapping`.

Just do a:

```
Product product = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Product.class);
```